# win cmd.exe in Vim tab

Tags: windows, vim, plugins, cmd

I'm looking for Vim/gVim plugin to use Windows shell (cmd.exe) (executing commands, retrieving output) in separate tab/frame.

There are a lots of such solutions for Linux, but I'm unable to do it in Win...

Comment: [conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) claims to support powershell, maybe that would suffice over cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Emacs, Vim is an editor, not an *environment* (thank Gawd :) and it is not (nor will ever be, according to what the developers have been saying for the past 20 years) designed to house a command prompt/shell in one of its buffers.

That being said, there are a couple of plugins that try to imitate that functionality. Some work better, some worse ... check'em out, and see what works best for you:

[cmd.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3040)
  [Shell.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=118)
  [**Conque**](http://code.google.com/p/conque/)

Just to add, I don't use any of the above - just found them on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org), so you're on your own from here on.

Comment: `shell.vim`(the lowercase-named one) is not really a terminal emulator - the name is misleading.

Comment: There is also [Conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) which is available for windows. Requires python support. I don’t know whether it’ll work for cmd, but on mainstream home page there is an example of launching python under windows.

Comment: @ZyX - THanks for the link! I don't think python is that rare on Windows nowadays (expecially amongst developers), so agree, Conque is really a nice plugin for that!